# Where did my father serve?

Tags: riddle

Look, where I walk!

Listen, when I speak!

Babyface, together with a dog?

Skull, together with a cat and a mouse?

The first time I was a King.

The second time my mother was a Queen.

But I have also been the Joker.

In the future I will awake as a Chess champion again.

Where did my father serve?

Comment: Skull with a cat and mouse reminds me of a Tarot card.

Comment: In one of the movies Jack Nicholson's character is cleanliness freak, while walking he chooses where to put his feet for next step (look, where I walk);in poster of  the movie "As good as it gets" Jack Nicholson is shown with a cute dog and Jack has played Joker in Batman

Comment: @Vikram - For what it's worth, Jack Nicholson's biological father may have been a King: Eddie King, original name Edgar Kirschfeld.

Comment: List of chess world champions: Steinitz, Lasker, Capablanca, Alekhine, Euwe, Botvinnik, Smyslov, Tal, Petrosian, Spassky, Fischer, Karpov, Kasparov, Kramnik, Khalifman, Anand, Ponomariov, Kasimdzhanov, Topalov, Carlsen.

Comment: Babyface must be [Jon Ericson](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15/jon-ericson) or [AJ Henderson](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/65/aj-henderson), judging from their profile pics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My current thought for the narrator:

> [Mark Hamill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hamill)

And thus, for the answer:

> Either The Empire, or the U.S. Navy, as that is where Hamill's father served.

---

"Look, where I walk!"

> "Look, walker in the sky" = "Luke Skywalker"

"Listen, when I speak!"

> Hamill has gained a reputation as a prolific voice actor.

"Babyface, together with a dog?"

> Hamill's role Babyface Boretti in the Scooby-Doo movies.

"Skull, together with cat and mouse!"

> In "Marvel Super Hero Squad: Comic Combat", Hamill did the voice of RED SKULL. Hamill did voice acting for th Tom & Jerry Kids episode "Droopy Man Returns".

"The first time, I was a king"

> Hamill's first appearance, according to IMDB, was as "King Blackyard / King Karuta" in "Exchange Student Zero"

"The second time my mother was a Queen."

> The mother of Luke Skywalker was Queen Padme Amidala.

"But I have also been the Joker"

> Hamill's role in the animated Batman series.

"In the future I will awake as a Chess champion again."

> In chess a champion is also referred to as a *Grandmaster*. 
>  In the Star Wars expanded universe, Luke Skywalker becomes *Grand Master* of the Jedi Order. 
>  Mark Hamill will be playing Luke Skywalker again in the new Star Wars film.

Comment: This looks right to me. Babyface Boretti, together with a dog. His mother was a queen in his biggest, most notable role. The cat and mouse clue isn't from the classics, but he's a character named The Skull in one of the newer-age movies.

Comment: Please elaborate on all clues

Comment: Maybe some reference to the upcoming Batman: Arkham Knight?

Comment: @PrincessTrevor (with a bit of help of @Gamow) Congratulations, you got it! I am impressed. Good job!

Comment: Huge thanks to @Gamow for adding a lot to back that up. Glad I was on the right track, this was a good one.

Comment: Just a missed subtle hint: "In the future I will AWAKE as a Chess champion again." - the new star wars film is called Force Awakens.

Answer (score 1):

> Great Britain?

Why?

> Well, England has a monarchy so it matches where you can have a king and queen. Your father died when you were young and his wife was still Queen so you became King. Your mother still was Queen. England did host some of the [World Chess Championships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_Chess_Championships), where some British players competed and even got into the finals. This proves that England used to be a great country for chess and the royal probably got involved ***a lot***.

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer. Sadly enough, none of the clues are interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Could the narrator be

> [Heath Ledger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath_Ledger)?

*The first time I was a King.*

> He played Oberon in the 1997 film *Paws*.

*The second time my mother was a Queen.*

> Probably a reference to another film...

*But I have also been the Joker.*

> He played the Joker in the 2008 film *The Dark Knight*.

*In the future I will awake as a Chess champion again.*

> He was going to direct and appear in a film version of [this novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Queen's_Gambit_(novel)) about a chess prodigy.

*Where did my father serve?*

> Kim Ledger served in **Australia**.

Comment: Please elaborate on all clues

Answer (score 0):

On a crusade in the Holy Land?

I know of only one world chess champion whose mother's name meant "queen", namely Bobby Fischer, whose mother's first name was Regina, Latin for queen.

"In the future I will awake" brings up thoughts of King Arthur...the Grail legends...the Fisher King.

So we get *The first time I was a king* (Fisher King) and *The second time my mother was a Queen* (World Chess Champion Bobby Fischer).

Does *Where did my father serve?* connect with "Whom does the Grail serve?"

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer... How did you think this would fit with the two first lines?

Comment: Is that a hint? :-) I didn't get that far; I was attacking through 5,6,8 and the possible feeling of 9. Can you say whether I was right or wrong to interpret *mother* and *father* literally?

Comment: Yes, father is literally. Mother is literally, but fictionally...:-)